# Confused with pointer and double pointer in the heap

Tags: c++

I'm getting confused about pointers and double pointers.

Suppose we have these

```
int* ptr = new int[2];
```

Here, ptr has the address of an array of size two in the heap that keeps int data right?

```
int** ptr = new int* [2];
```

Here, ptr has the address two pointers in the heap and these two pointers can point to some int data.

Is my thinking here correct?

Comment: "and these two pointers points to some int data" - not yet they don't.

Comment: Sorry I meant that these two pointers can point to some int data. Is that right?

Comment: The rest of your thought is correct. Those `int` pointers are in dynamic memory just as your first snippet put two `int` in dynamic memory.

Comment: ptr has the address **of the first element of** an array of two elements in the heap that keeps `int` data.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost correct: in the first case you assign a pointer to a memory block in the heap sufficient for storing two `int`s, which can be considered an `int` array of size two.

The second `ptr` is assigned a pointer to a memory block in the heap sufficient for storing two pointers to `int`. However, these pointers do not point to anything in particular until you assign them some value<sup>*</sup>, in the same way that you assign other pointers. For example, you can make the second `ptr` to make an array of two `int` arrays, like this:

```
int** ptr = new int* [2];
ptr[0] = new int[2];
ptr[1] = new int[2];
```

<sup>*</sup> The same is true for `int`s from your first code snippet: their value is indeterminate until you assign them.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int* ptr = new int[2];
> ```
>
> Here, `ptr` has the address of an array of size two in the heap that keeps `int` data right?

Yes.

> ```
> int** ptr = new int* [2];
> ```
>
> Here, `ptr` has the address two pointers in the heap and these two pointers can point to some `int` data.

Yes, but just to clarify, `ptr` holds the address of a heap-allocated array of two `int*` values, and those two pointers then point at `int` data stored elsewhere in memory.